# How to query an array inside a document using PyMongo?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, mongodb-query, pymongo-3.x

I am using python 3.6 and the latest version of mongod.
[This is my data base.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYkZJ.png) Each document is called 'Module'.

I am trying to get all the message_logs of a specific module, that have a specific 'des' value.

I tried something like this:

```
filter_param = {
'info.id': module_id,
'message_logs': {'$elemMatch': {'des': dev_id}}
}
proj_param = {
    'message_logs.$': 1,
    '_id': 0
}
try:
    return db.modules.find_one(filter_param, projection=proj_param)['message_logs']
except Exception:
    return "Unconfigured device"
```

But I got only the first message_log that matched 'des'.

I would also like to know how to get the last matched element instead of the first one.

Comment: If you want "multiple matches" then you use `$filter` just as shown in the linked examples. And before you ask *"..how with pymongo?"* then the answer is **exactly the same as the demonstrated JavaScript syntax** since python dict construction is basically identical.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `find_one` which will fetch only the first result that it finds. You should use `find` to get all the results.

i.e:

```
try:
    return db.modules.find(filter_param, projection=proj_param)['message_logs']
except Exception:
    return "Unconfigured device"
```

Comment: That's not it. I'm getting the same outcome..

Comment: `find` returns a cursor.. you have loop through it. BTW, what version of PyMongo driver are you using?